# Android studio SQLite managedQuery с условием части значения

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdk, android-sqlite

Ну вот например я получаю все значения, равные моему условию:

```
cursor = managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        "artist = ?",
        new String[] {"Eminem"},
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

А как описать такое условие, что бы возвращало все значения, СОДЕРЖАЩИЕ мое слово, типо поля `Eminem ft D12` которое не попадает под обычное равенство как сверху.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось банально, всего лишь привел в соответствие с sql

> ```
>   cursor = getContentResolver().query(
>                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
>                   null,
>                   "artist LIKE ?",
>                   new String[] {"%Eminem%"},  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
> ```